# File service latency is high, How to troubleshoot?

Tags: http, tcp, tcpdump, file-server

This service is a file upload service and the request packet capture in the live network is as follows:

- The data uploaded by the client is halfway through, and then it will not be sent
- The server sends keep alive to maintain the heartbeat.
- After 30 seconds, the client uploads the data again. Ask the boss how to solve it.

Since it is an online service, the capture file of the client cannot be obtained and it is impossible to determine which segment the location is.

Capture file:
[image: Capture file]

Comment: what does "Ask the boss how to solve it." mean?

Comment: In China, boss refers to someone who understands this knowledge. sorry

Comment: oh, right, so did you ask the boss like you stated in the question?

Comment: How can we answer without knowing the involved online service and the upload mechanism? And what does it mean "the client uploads the data again" - does the client restart from the beginning, or does the upload continue after a 30-seconds pause?